# WPF Interactive Region в Designer Surface

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

В разметке создал свойство (например, `MenuRegion`), которое отображаю с помощью ContentPresenter в своем `UserControl (Template)`. Есть желание, чтобы заданное свойство (которое содержит, к примеру, `Button`) могло редактироваться в редакторе VS. Т.е. я хочу сделать `CustomControl` со своим свойством и чтобы оно было редактируемо в VS Designer, как Header в `GroupBox`.

Что пробовал:

1. Найти информацию в google: все не то.
2. Выставил `[Category("Content")]` на свойство - не помогло.
3. Смотрел в родную сборку, как это реализовано, но там ничего дополнительного нет, но возможно, что я что-то упустил.

Есть вероятность, что редактор поддерживает только родные свойства .NET, но я надеюсь, что это не так.

Comment: Может, вы объявили обыкновенное свойство вместо `DependencyProperty`?

Comment: VladD, к сожалению не все так просто